# What is the consequence of not closing a BufferedWriter

Tags: java, io, bufferedwriter, writer

Suppose I have a `BufferedWriter` that has written 5000 rows (some of which are not yet flushed).

What are the consequences if I do not `close()` this instance at the end of my program?

Comment: Try it and see. _Then_ ask if the documentation doesn't explain it and/or you don't understand it. Explain why that is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why can't you just tell me the answer? From my reading of meta it is okay to ask googlable answers (e.g. "how do you generate random numbers in python"). In addition I can only test one small case and there could be edge cases that a developer can elucidate.

Comment: I'd imagine anything on this [list of bad things](http://www.cockeyed.com/magic/bad_3.php).

Comment: Jason C that is funny :-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't `close()` it before your program ends, buffered data that hasn't been written yet will never be written.

`BufferedWriter` does all of its buffering in Java land (as opposed to relying solely on the OS's lower level buffers). Therefore it takes an explicit action to flush the buffers and close the files, as this does not happen automatically when your program exits (due primarily to the GC'd nature of Java and the lack of guarantees on when and if, e.g., `finalize()` is called).

So anything in the `BufferedWriter`'s buffers that's still there when the program exits ends up getting lost forever.

You should make it a habit of `close()`ing streams when you are done with them (and `null`ing any references out to them as well so the GC can discard the object; this doesn't have any impact on `BufferedWriter`s behavior, but it is a good general practice). At the bare minimum, if you've written important data and you need to ensure it has been written to disk whether you need to close the stream or not, you can explicitly call `flush()` as needed.

The source code for `BufferedWriter` [can be found here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/BufferedWriter.java?av=f), if you'd like to take a look at the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It might not actually finish writing the data to wherever it's writing the data. So you'll lose whatever wasn't written yet.

The problem with a question like this is that it makes people wonder why you would ask. Are you *trying* to be a terrible person and not close your writers? Do you actually *have* a situation where closing the writer is something you don't want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like closing streams, so use try-with-resource, new feature introduced in JDK 1.7, it will close all the such objects which implements Closable interface